Random slopes in a linear mixed-effects model
In my experiment, I have 3 conditions for 100 participants (N = 100):

CHOICE: a number between 0 and 30.
EMOTION: a number between 1 and 7 or between -250 and +250.
PERFORMANCE: mean reaction times.

I use a linear mixed-effects model to examine whether and how CHOICE, PERFORMANCE, or their interaction impact EMOTION. The model I have been using is:
model = lmer(EMOTION ~ scale(CHOICE) * scale(PERFORMANCE) +(1 + scale(CHOICE) * scale(PERFORMANCE) | Participant), data = data, REML = FALSE, control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 10000000)))
However, I get the following warning:
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
From my understanding, this warning suggests that the model might be overfitted. A common recommendation is to "simplify" the model, for example, by removing CHOICE * PERFORMANCE as random slopes.
However, I am hesitant about doing this since simplifying the model might increase the risk of Type I errors.
Is there a better way to address this issue without compromising the robustness of the model?

"A number between 1 and 7 or between -250 and 250" scares me. Which is it? Also, are these numbers integers? Also, why (1 + scale(choice)*scale(performance)?  And, did you investigate colinearity?

Why is your random effect structure so complex?
Start with a simpler random effects structure and progressively add complexity if the model supports it. For example: model_simple <- lmer(EMOTION ~ scale(CHOICE) * scale(PERFORMANCE) + 1 | Participant), data = data, REML = FALSE)
